# DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnModelCreating' in any way that makes use of the model that is being created

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

**Detail:** I am trying to seed some test data before my application start. I am using `.net6` & following [link](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasdata-method)

**Error:**

> EntityType    '((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<TestApp_40_xUnit_MVC_LibraryApp.Models.Book>)this.Books).EntityType'
> threw an exception of type
> 'System.InvalidOperationException'    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType
> {System.InvalidOperationException}
>
> **Message** An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A
> DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnModelCreating' in any way
> that makes use of the model that is being created.

**getting an error on line:**

> protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

debug: even with error, application runs file but no test data is inserted

**DbContext file**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var _books = new List<Book>()
        {
           new Book()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Title="Managing Oneself",
                Description="We live in an age of unprecedented opportunity: with ambition, drive, and talent, you can rise to the top of your chosen profession, regardless of where you started out...",
                Author= "Peter Drucker"
            }
        };

        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasData(_books);
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("this-is-just-test"));
builder.Services.AddTransient<IBookService, BookService>();
```

**Model class**

```
public class Book
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would put call to that seed function in "program.cs".  See this as an example:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#seed-the-database

Comment: @pcalkins great that worked for me. You want to add a quick answer so that I can give you credit and close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the call to the seed function in "program.cs". See this as an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#seed-the-database

That way it executes after the table is created...